# Dynamic NSTabViewItem constraints

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm dynamically adding NSTabViewItem in NSTabView, using this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var inputTabs: NSTabView!
```

...

```
let rgbInputController = ForegroundRGBInputController(nibName: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "RGBInputView"), bundle: nil)
let rgbInputItem = NSTabViewItem(identifier: "RGB")
rgbInputItem.label = "RGB"
rgbInputItem.view = rgbInputController.view
self.inputTabs!.addTabViewItem(rgbInputItem)
```

The view is added, but not correctly displayed.

[RGB tab with size issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToNOY.png)

After playing with the tabs, and the App width, the tab finally displays correctly.

[RGB tab displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx9BX.png)

I believe this is a constraints issue, but I have difficulties to fix it.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but it seems to lack an answer and I've been able to resolve something like this... for clarification, are you using constraints in your views?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `setNeedsLayout` on the input controller view? That should flag that it needs to be laid out again. You could also try `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`, as the `intrinsicContentSize` of your view may be being used to indicate its initial width and height.

Comment: Yes `rgbInputItem.view!.layout()` and 
        `rgbInputItem.view!.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`